# Types of webpage error codes

Tags: http-status-code-404

I am creating a webpage for another company. If this website is created wrong or if there is any errors I can't sell it to the company. I know there is several types of http status codes. I know for example there is the 404 error when the address is wrong but I don't know any of the other http status codes. Can anybody please tell me what they are?

EDIT:

I also want to know wich can be styled by me. So for example a 404 status code can be styled on my own way by saying the location of my document in an .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the possible codes. Mostly for handling error scenarios we care about **400** and **500** series.

**Solution**:
check the http response code belongs to 400 or 500 series, if yes then redirect the page to some error page defining the error message what went wrong or define some custom messages to show to client (more meaningful to end users). That way the application would handle error scenarios gracefully.

```
->  100:
return "Continue";
->  101:
return "Switching Protocols";
->  102:
return "Processing (WebDAV)";
->  200:
return "OK";
->  201:
return "Created";
->  202:
return "Accepted";
->  203:
return "Non-Authoritative Information";
->  204:
return "No Content";
->  205:
return "Reset Content";
->  206:
return "Partial Content";
->  207:
return "Multi-Status (WebDAV)";
->  300:
return "Multiple Choices";
->  301:
return "Moved Permanently";
->  302:
return "Found";
->  303:
return "See Other";
->  304:
return "Not Modified";
->  305:
return "Use Proxy";
->  307:
return "Temporary Redirect";
->  400:
return "Bad Request";
->  401:
return "Unauthorized";
->  402:
return "Payment Required";
->  403:
return "Forbidden";
->  404:
return "Not Found";
->  405:
return "Method Not Allowed";
->  406:
return "Not Acceptable";
->  407:
return "Proxy Authentication Required";
->  408:
return "Request Time-out";
->  409:
return "Conflict";
->  410:
return "Gone";
->  411:
return "Length Required";
->  412:
return "Precondition Failed";
->  413:
return "Request Entity Too Large";
->  414:
return "Request-URI Too Large";
->  415:
return "Unsupported Media Type";
->  416:
return "Requested range not satisfiable";
->  417:
return "Expectation Failed";
->  422:
return "Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV)";
->  423:
return "Locked (WebDAV)";
->  424:
return "Failed Dependency (WebDAV)";
->  500:
return "Internal Server Error";
->  501:
return "Not Implemented";
->  502:
return "Bad Gateway";
->  503:
return "Service Unavailable";
->  504:
return "Gateway Time-out";
->  505:
return "HTTP Version not supported";
->  507:
return "Insufficient Storage (WebDAV)";
->  510:
return "Not Extended";
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a full list of HTTP status codes here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for http status codes? If yes, Please check this wiki link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

There is a few places to look at:

[HTTP Status Code Errors](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findtheproblem/tp/browsererror.htm),

[List of HTTP status codes - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

[HTTP Error and Status Codes Explained](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkprotocolsip/tp/http-error-and-status-codes-explained.htm)

100-199 : informational status

200-299 : success status

300-399 : redirection status

400-499 : client errors

500-599 : server errors

Actually it's just the 400-500 codes that's important. Others is also important but not as important.